# How can I fix "Design editor is unavailable until a successful build" error?

Tags: android-studio

I started to learn Android Studio. I try to echo out simple "Hello World":

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

but when I clicked "design" view, this error is showing?

> Design editor is unavailable until a successful build

How can I fix this error.

[image]

[image]

I just noticed that my xml code is causing error. Is that why this may be not working?

Comment: what version of AS are you using ?

Answer (score 335):

Go to File > Sync Project with Gradles Files.

Comment: In IntelliJ you have to look in "Tools > Android >"

Comment: 1.Build -> Clean Project

2.Build -> Rebuild Project

3.File -> Sync project with Gradle files

4.File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart .

I did all of this. But still the same problem

Answer (score 42):

Quit the `Android Studio` ( not close the project `Quit` the `Android Studio`) then open the project and go to `Android Studio > Build > Clean Project`

Then 
`Android Studio > File > Sync Project with Gradles Files` as the pic below

[image]

If your problem still exists then click the Install build tool as the pic below and then 
`Android Studio > File > Sync Project with Gradles Files`

[image]

Comment: For me only doing "Sync Project with Gradles Files" did the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

None of the above worked for me. what worked for me is to go to `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Answer (score 18):

I faced same issue even after rebuilding my project multiple times successfully. I closed the project and re-opened, issue resolved.

Comment: Simpler that syncing project with gradle files? I don't think so

Answer (score 13):

1. First, find your `build.gradle` in your all modules in project, include `app/build.gradle`. Find the `compileSdkVersion` inside `android` tag, in this case, compile sdk version is 30:

[image: In this case, SDK version is 30]

2. Next, open **SDK Manager > SDK Platforms**, check for install SDK versions that there modules using, then apply to install selected platforms.
   After installed, go to menu **File > Sync project with Gradle files...**.

[image: Install the API version which module requires]

*This issue often appear when project has many modules, each module use different compile SDK version, so app may be able to build but IDE have some issue while processing your resources.*

Comment: Thanks! The only thing that worked for me. App had 2 modules, both had different compileSdkVersions. I was missing one of the SDKs.

Answer (score 7):

Simply restart the Android Studio. In my case, I was offline before starting the Android Studio, but online when I did restart.

Comment: make sure ur windows date is updated. i had date problem.

Answer (score 6):

Do this

Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 4):

Install the missing platform and sync the project.
[image: [press to install automatically]]

Answer (score 3):

Go online before starting android studio.  Then go file->New project
Follow onscreen steps.  Then wait It will download the necessary files over internet. And that should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem after i added a line in my `build.gradle` file.

```
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
```

**Solution:**
I changed this line to

```
implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
```

and then pressed `sync again`.

Tada! all was working again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because it didn't like that I left the minSDK and targeSdk in the manifest. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

just click file in your android studio
then click Sync Project with Gradle Files..

if it won't work,
click Build
click Clean Project.

it always work for me

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK Platform API Level that the project requires for `targetSdkVersion` may not exist.

Check the console of the **Event Log** tab of the IDE to see any errors eg. of the following type:

```
Gradle sync failed:
com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.issues.SdkPlatformNotFoundException:
Module: 'common' platform 'android-29' not found.
```

Then install some API Level (29) in **SDK Manager -> SDK Platforms** and finally Sync again.

Answer (score 0):

Edit you xml file in Notepad++ and build it again. It's work for me

Answer (score 0):

I have the latest Android Studio 3.6.1 and yet couldn't build a simple 'Hello World' app as documented here "https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-hello-world/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#3". 
I applied various steps discussed above including the 2 most viable options which should have really solved this issue,

1. '**File->Sync Project with Gradle Files**' and
2. '**File->Invalidate Caches/Restart**' but to no avail.

Even though, I suspect standard answer should be one of these 2 options only for most, but for me the resolution came only after I went inside the 'File->Project Structure' and checked my SDK versions configured!
Android Studio and Gradle were using different JDK versions and locations.

- **Android Studio:** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241
- **Gradle:** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2

*I had previously defined my JAVA_HOME environment variable by downloading latest JAVA SDK on my own from ORACLE website. Where Gradle was using the %JAVA_HOME% JAVA SDK version and Android Studio the built in SDK which came along with Android Studio.*

Once I switched both to versions JDK 1.8.* (*Any version as long as it is JDK 1.8.* for that matter*) then simple 'File->Synch...' option worked perfectly fine for me!

Good luck the solution is in between one of these 2 options only if you are stuck, just ensure you validate JDK versions being referred to!

Answer (score 0):

there are different solutions to this problem but I at the first u have to check to (build.gradle) maybe it empty. this especially if u downloaded code, not u created
and u will find just this line "// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules."
 in this case, u need to open a new project and make copy-paste.then check the SDK and other settings.finally u have to sync

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `Windows Firewall` was blocking Android Studio (i.e. `java.exe` from Android Studio's `jre/bin` folder) from connecting to sites and downloading data. After Windows asked me if I wanted to allow the app through the firewall, I had to do a manual sync `File -> Sync project with gradle files`. After that, things were still disfunctional, a manual download of an SDK version 28 was necessary from `Tools -> SDK Manager`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in corporate setting where there is a proxy server, double check your proxy settings.

1. Go File -> Settings
2. Search for Proxy.
3. Fill out as appropreate.
4. Test connection.

If you think you fat-fingered the password, there is a Clear passwords button you can click to where you can re-enter your creds. HTH

Answer (score -1):

I had tried to change SDK Version:

Check below image: In that I changed **27** from **Android P**

[image]

Comment: If you can't open the design view, how can you see this option?

Comment: I dont have any option to view this, so it might me something by text designer