# How can I fix the "design editor is not available until a successful build" in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

How can I fix the `Design editor is not unavailable until a successful build` error in android studio as seen in this image below
[image: this image].

Comment: see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47289011/android-studio-how-can-i-fix-design-editor-is-unavailable-until-a-successful-bu

Answer (score 5):

Do what it says. Build the project.

For example, on windows use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

Comment: I TRY BUT NO RESULT

Answer (score 4):

Goto Gradle `Scripts/gradle-wrapper.properties(Gradle Version)`.
In the file you can find the `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`, replace `https` with `http` and click 'Sync Project with Gradle files'.