# Android Studio how can I fix "Design editor is unavailable until a successful rebuild

Tags: android

[That's the error page I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYG6v.png)
Am new to android development. I just want to start my first Android app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio How can I fix "Design editor is unavailable until a successful build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47289011/android-studio-how-can-i-fix-design-editor-is-unavailable-until-a-successful-bu)

Answer (score 2):

Just sync your progect with gradles. It will be solved if there is no error exists!
**File** --> **Sync Project with Gradle Files**
Look at the screenshot:
[image]