# Android Application Failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-emulator, android-developer-api

I am trying to start my first application on android studio and this was the beginning

```
 Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
```

I think it is the problem occurred when syncing Gradle and SDK files for the project, I tried to restart android but the error is still occurred , I also tried to switch off the firewall defender but the problem not solved.

I tried to change the project structure setting and upgrade my gradle:

[image]

The error was gone but the application still failed syncing the gradle files:

[image]

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried to delete .android file and restart the android but nothing is working.
Can any body give a solution to this issue it seems frustrating !!!
Here is the log:

```
  4:10 PM   Gradle sync failed: The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.5-all.zip' does not exist.
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (2 s 225 ms)
```

Comment: The issue could be caused by anything. Consider including your `build.gradle` file(s) in your question

Comment: I had just edited it

Comment: What gradle version are you using? i.e. output of `gradle --version`

Comment: gradle version is 3.6.2. the same as android version 3.6.2

Comment: That's the problem. The version of the plugin you are using requires gradle version `5.6.4+`. If you are using gradle 3.6.2, then you need to downgrade the plugin to `< 3.0.0` See this [table](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)

Comment: Did you try to turn off the gralde offline mode?

Comment: yes I tried that see the edited version of my question the error was gone but the application still failed syncing with gradle

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your version of gradle is outdated with respect to the version of the plugin you are attempting to use.

You need to either upgrade your gradle version to something above 5.6.4 or downgrade your plugin to something below 3.0.0

See this [table](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle) for more details

Comment: the error was gone but it is still not working properly "DESIGN EDITOR IS UNAVAILABLE UNTIL AFTER THE PROJECT SUCCESSFULLY SYNC"

Comment: @NadineMartini you have to be more specific. What is "not working properly"?

Comment: DESIGN EDITOR IS UNAVAILABLE UNTIL AFTER THE PROJECT SUCCESSFULLY SYNC

Comment: @NadineMartini that's a different question to the one you previously asked. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53195701/android-studio-design-editor-is-unavailable-until-after-a-successful-project-syn/53424315

Comment: nothing worked I tried to sync project with gradle and I tried invalidate cashes and restart