# How to open Activity_main.xml on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

When I try to open the `activity_main.xml` I get `Design editor is unavailable until a successful build`.

I fixed it before by using the clean project and rebuild project but it does not work when I opened the file again. I tried the solutions found on this answer: [Android studio design editor is unavailable until after a successful project sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53195701/android-studio-design-editor-is-unavailable-until-after-a-successful-project-syn/53424315)  but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: have to tried to sync your gradle?

Comment: Yes I have and its still not working.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can create a new one.
**step 1:** `Right Click` on `res` folder, then create a new `android resource directory` and change the resource type to `layout`.

[image: step 01]

**step 2:** `Right Click` on the newly created `layout` folder, go to `new` and create a `Layout Resource File`. Name it as "**activity_main.xml**" and give it some time to load it.

[image: step 02]

[image: step 02.1]

**step 3:** Do not forget to include the `activity_main.xml` inside the `MainActivity.kt` using `setContentView` method and remove the `setContent` method as well as the codes below `@composable` if you want to avoid the default `Jetpack` setup.

[image: step 3]

Any doubt, just leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the files, open folder res (resources), after press layout and finally there is the activity_main.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Open your android studio and go to **File** and click on **Sync Project with Gradle Files** this will solve your problem. As cleaning your project and rebuilding it won't work unless you sync the project.

After the gradle has finish building, you can go to file menu and click on Sync Project with Gradle Files which is present here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response but it still doesn't work. I have also tried opening a completely new file but this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Then its really a weird problem. Can you tell how this problem arise? Have you upgraded your android studio or gradle version?  Has it ever worked fine in the past?