# Design editor is unavailable until next gradle sync

Tags: android, c++, linux, chromium

I've opened an Android project in Android Studio, while Opening a XML file,I am not able to see the design editor as the error is [Design editor is unavailable until next gradle sync].

I am able to see the code as I am not able to see design editor due to which I am not able to do my work.

Even in Main menu in studio, The sync with gradle files button is not there,gradle icon on the top left side of studio is not there.

What should I do help me.

I searched over the youtube,LLM & stackoverflow but didn't got any solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio design editor is unavailable until after a successful project sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53195701/android-studio-design-editor-is-unavailable-until-after-a-successful-project-syn)

Comment: Actually,I am building android browser based on chromium which is built using ninja build system.

So,is it possible to make design using xml using design editor of Android studio as gradle is build system too. ??