# apps in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

i have downloaded the latest version of android studio, after starting it and opening all the files, it shows "failed to open the zip file(graddle)". and when i open the content_main.xml it shows "design unavailable until after a successful project sync" i have been trying and clicking the graddle button (and that link too) many times (i am doing this from 1-2 days) but still it is not working (and my net is also good). what should i do? and the emulator is also working. should i download abdroid studio again?

are there any other ways to do?

Comment: Could you please explain how you are trying to open/import this zip file?

Comment: For the error **"design unavailable until after a successful project sync"** try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51568416/13031115)

Comment: @DanielBeleza, It just says that graddle zip could not be downloaded.

Comment: @MdBasha as you have given the link,  i have tried the methods,  but still nothings works out. pls help

Comment: Try File ---> Invalidate Caches / Restart and click "Invalidate and Restart" option.  Then do as per the instructions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42654435/13031115)